# APKLIB (Holoeverywhere) is not imported to Android project using Maven - m2e-android

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, m2e

I have created a new Maven project, using android-quickstart artifact Id. There is no error and apk runs on a mobile phone - okay.
When I download Holoeverywhere project from git and link it with my project as a library, it also works.

But I want to link Holoeverywhere to my project using Maven (pom.xml). It's better to import everything using pom.xml than Import->...Use Library...

Dependency in pom.xml itself shows no error, but pom.xml shows this error:
[image]

Same error shows up in all projects with apklib dependency in pom.xml. Some projects need these types of dependencies and I can't use them.

Does m2e-android 0.4.3 really support apklib?

Comment: Does the Holoeverywhere Android Library have a pom? Does its version match the one in your app dependencies?

Comment: Yes, it has - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.holoeverywhere/library/1.6.8 . I think this problem is related to m2e plugin. It's written that m2e-android 0.4.3 supports apklibs, but..

Comment: There are several integration tests to verify this behaviour, I'm sure m2e-android supports apklibs. What you might not know is that the ADT still requires you to have the Android Library source code checked out in your local workspace. Have you done this?

Comment: Yes, now I have to link libraries as locally stored Android libraries. But then no maven is required. I don't understand, why I am using maven then. In a perfect world, I have a pom.xml with dependencies defined and Eclipse should download and use all of them (as in normal Java project).

Comment: m2e-android automatically links the projects for you and also properly manages transitive dependencies. Unfortunately, the ADT requires the Android Library source code be checked out normally and there is no way to always correctly reverse export the Android Library source code until the ADT supports the new AAR format.